# Is there a way to make this random URL redirect script not repeat the same URL more than once?

Tags: php, redirect, random

So I want to add a little bit of fun or "randomness" into a webpage, having a tab when clicked, redirect the user to a random URL. But, I want to make it where it doesn't repeat that URL if the user was just redirected to that.

So lets say user 1 clicks "random" and he is taken to http://google.com/ But then, he heads back to my page, and clicks on "random" a second time, I would like it to take him else where, and not back to http:/google.com/ It's fine if he is redirected to http://google.com/ if he goes back a 3rd time, but I just don't want it to repeat the same URL if they just visited that URL.

Is this doable in PHP the way I am describing it? Or is it more complex then I think it is?

This is currently what I am working with: (I ain't really PHP savvy at all, that's why I am asking).

```
<?php
$urls = array(
"www.google.com",
"www.youtube.com",
"www.facebook.com"
);
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
header("Location: http://$url");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using sessions:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function checkUrl($url, $urls){
        if(count($_SESSION['visited']) == count($urls)){
               $_SESSION['visited'] = Array();
        }
        if(in_array($url, $_SESSION['visited'])){
             $url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
             checkUrl($url, $urls);
        }
        else{
             $_SESSION['visited'][] = $url;
             header("Location: http://$url");
        }
    }
    $urls = array(
        "www.google.com",
        "www.youtube.com",
        "www.facebook.com"
    );
    $url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
    checkUrl($url, $urls);
?>
```

**edit:**

Implemented a reset when all adresses are visited

Comment: I've uploaded this to my server, and it seems that after running it about 3 times, the script just ends at a white page and loads no where.

Comment: I seem to still be getting the white page. Not sure if it's just me though. Could you give it a visit? http://travisx.com/1.php

Comment: I'm at work an cant test this properly right now, could possibly be a typo from my, but it should work

Comment: I've now tested this and it is working as expected for me... are you trying the exact code that i've written above or are you modifying it?

Comment: Have not modified it. Just a direct copy n paste. Did you try it more than 3-4 times? Did you do them quickly, or wait at least a few seconds before re attempting? I went through the URLs quickly, and that's when I noticed they stopped working. Sorry if I make absolutely no sense, typing on a mobile now.

Comment: I've just done it on my phone and is working correctly.

Comment: Ive also tested it just now and it is working correctly for me aswell... The problem must be elsewhere